# Extraer palabra random de una lista en Java

Tags: java, lista

Necesito extraer de un archivo txt palabras random, ya logré imprimir las palabras de forma random pero cómo podría imprimir sola una de la lista?

```
    try {
        archivo = new File("n.txt");
        leerArchivo = new FileReader(archivo);
        leerTxt = new BufferedReader(leerArchivo);
        String linea;
        while((linea = leerTxt.readLine()) != null) {
            lista.add(linea);
            int rand = new Random().nextInt(lista.size());
            System.out.println(lista.get(rand));

        }

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Te recomiendo leer este post, espero te sirva: http://puntocomnoesunlenguaje.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-ficheros-acceso-aleatorio.html

Comment: De hecho ya lo tienes: `int rand = new Random().nextInt(lista.size());
System.out.println(lista.get(rand));`